# Почему $model->validate() всегда возвращает false

Tags: yii, валидация

Причем даже не работают рулезы(вернее нет ошибок на странице). Это произошло после добавления элементов в форму и применения соответствующей миграции. Что я мог сделать не так?

```
try {$model->validate();}
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo 'errors:';
            var_dump($model->getErrors());
            exit();
        }
```

возвращает`array (size=11)
  'full_name' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Необходимо заполнить поле «Наименование(ФИО)».' (length=86)
  'inn' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Необходимо заполнить поле «ИНН».' (length=60)
  'ogrn' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Необходимо заполнить поле «ОГРН».' (length=62)
  'p_accounts' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Необходимо заполнить поле «р\c».' (length=58)
  'bank_name' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Необходимо заполнить поле «Наименование банка».' (length=89)
  'bic_bank' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Необходимо заполнить поле «БИК банка».' (length=71)
  'corr_account' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Необходимо заполнить поле «корр\с».' (length=65)
  'kpp' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Необходимо заполнить поле «КПП».' (length=60)
  'yurid_adress' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Необходимо заполнить поле «Юридический адрес».' (length=87)
  'fakt_adress' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Необходимо заполнить поле «Фактический адрес».' (length=87)
  'polnoe_fio_dir' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Необходимо заполнить поле «Полное ФИО директора».' (length=92)`

```
try {$model->save();}
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                echo 'errors:';
                var_dump($model->getErrors());
                exit();
            }
```

возвращает тоже самое. Что я еще смогу сделать чтобы узнать где ошибка?

Comment: Приведите полный код экшена и модели

Comment: проблему я уже давно решил. не помню как правда